# Remove duplicates from Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have something like this:

```
  items: { _id: number; place: SomeAddressClassDto }[] = [];
  sessionItem: { _id: number; place: SomeAddressClassDto };

  createAddressList() {

    this.service.getWorkingPlaces().subscribe((items) => {
      this.items = items;

      this.sessionItem = {
        place: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentPlace')),
        _id: this.items.length,
      };

      this.items.push(this.sessionItem);

    // _.uniqBy(this.items, 'place')

      const idx = items.findIndex((item) => this.service.comparePlaces(item.place, 
 this.service.getCurrentWorkingPlace()));
      if (idx !== -1) this.radiobox.option = `${idx}`;
    });
  }
```

I am trying to remove any duplicates from 'items' array using the method _uniqBy, but it isn't working. I think it's because for this items._id are always different but items.place could be equal and if are I would like to get rid of this.

Maybe better way is to check is the same items.place is already in that array, but no idea how to do this.

EDIT: 
To be more specify, items looks like this:

```
0: place: {name, street, city, etc...}
   _id: 0
```

So it is possible to have very similar object whitch is differnet only by one property in place{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `_id` to determine if the value is unique. If you use `place` the value may always be unique since they could be different instances of the same class.(I can't tell from your code if this is the case)

```
createAddressList() {
    this.service.getWorkingPlaces().subscribe((items) => {
        this.items = items;

        this.sessionItem = {
            place: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentPlace')),
            _id: this.items.length,
        };

        this.items.push(this.sessionItem);

        _.uniqBy(this.items, '_id');

        const idx = items.findIndex((item) => this.service.comparePlaces(item.place, this.service.getCurrentWorkingPlace()));
        if (idx !== -1) {
            this.radiobox.option = `${idx}`;
        }
    });
}
```

Alternately, you could use a  property from inside `place` to determine if they are unique like this:

```
 _.uniqBy(this.items, (x) => x.place && x.place.someOtherPropertyInsideOfPlace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.Prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.find()` to create an array that has no duplicates based on the `place` property.

As an example:

```
const test = [
  { _id: 1, place: 'a' },
  { _id: 2, place: 'a' },
  { _id: 3, place: 'a' },
  { _id: 4, place: 'b' },
  { _id: 5, place: 'c' },
]

const noDups = test.reduce((accum, current)=> {
  if(!accum.find(item => item.place === current.place))
    accum.push(current)
  return accum
}, [])
console.log(noDups)
```

`reduce()` will create a new array (in this case, the `accum` variable is being initialized as an empty array), but only add new items in the new array if the `.place` property is unique, if it doesn't already find an item with the same `.place` property

Answer (score 0):

- declaring a simple object array with id and place properties.
- Removing duplicates by javascript filter function.
- filter function will remove the objects from array whose place is paris.

```js
var arr = [{
    _id: 1,
    place: 'paris'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    place: 'tokyo'
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    place: 'ontario'
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    place: 'paris'
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    place: 'karachi'
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
    place: 'paris'
  },
  {
    _id: 7,
    place: 'new york'
  }
];

var newArray = arr.filter((self, item, index) => index.findIndex(t => (t.place === self.place)) === item);

console.log(newArray);
```